# IOS - Program Produces a Apple Mach-O Linker Error With IOS 6.1 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, compiler-errors

Hey so I'm using the arc compatible Reachability headers found here https://gist.github.com/darkseed/1182373 and for some reason my code now throws a "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" when I compile it for the iPhone 6.1 and iPad 6.1 simulators.  The project compiles on all devices we have tested it on (iPad, iPhone 4, iPhone 3s and iPhone 5) but for some reason fails on the simulators.  It seems to have an issue with the newly added reachability .h and .m files, here is the compiler log.

```
Ld /Users/scottlarose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coffee-fvbhtkgwidvsobcpnfvptcvzzrdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Coffee.app/Coffee normal i386
    cd "/Users/scottlarose/Documents/workspace/xcode workspace/iPhone workspace/Coffee"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/scottlarose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coffee-fvbhtkgwidvsobcpnfvptcvzzrdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/scottlarose/Documents/workspace/xcode workspace/iPhone workspace/Coffee/XMPPFramework/XMPPFramework/Vendor/libidn" -F/Users/scottlarose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coffee-fvbhtkgwidvsobcpnfvptcvzzrdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/scottlarose/Documents/workspace/xcode workspace/iPhone workspace/Coffee" -filelist /Users/scottlarose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coffee-fvbhtkgwidvsobcpnfvptcvzzrdr/Build/Intermediates/Coffee.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Coffee.build/Objects-normal/i386/Coffee.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -lresolv -lxml2 -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework StoreKit -framework Social -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz.1.1.3 -lsqlite3 -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework AdSupport -framework Accounts -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework Parse -lidn -framework SystemConfiguration -o /Users/scottlarose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coffee-fvbhtkgwidvsobcpnfvptcvzzrdr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Coffee.app/Coffee

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/scottlarose/Documents/workspace/xcode workspace/iPhone workspace/Coffee/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/scottlarose/Documents/workspace/xcode workspace/iPhone workspace/Coffee/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
      +[PFInternalUtils(Reachability) isParseReachable] in Parse(PFInternalUtils.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[PFCommandCache init] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[PFCommandCache dealloc] in Parse(PFCommandCache.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your project doesn't have the required framework.
**Reachability** class needs `SystemConfiguration.framework` to be execute.

Comment: It wasn't a framework issue ;)

Comment: I figured it out but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means you have added some code that requires a specific Framework that has not been added to the project.

Comment: I figured it out but thanks for the attempt

Comment: Care to share what it was or as you have the answer you're not bothered helping others?